# How to pass button value from a modal window (that uses partial view) to the parent view

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

here is the button on the partial view,

```
<button type="button" name="btnid" id="bparentid" value="@item.Itemid " class="btn btn-success" onclick="alert(@item.Itemid)">Select</button>
```

Just to check if it holds the value I put razor alert function, and  I want the button value to be passed to the parent view on button click using this hidden input form in the parent view

```
<input asp-for="Itemid" type="hidden" value=" @item.Itemid" />
```

**More detail:**

I have two tables for recording children and their parents separately, 
Here is the Model

```
public class Children
{
   [Key]
    public int ChildID { get; set; }
    [Required] [StringLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Parentid")]
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
  }

public class Parent
{
    [Key]
    public int Parentid { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Children> Children { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the Create method controller for posting new children record with their parent information:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ChildID,FirstName")] Children children, int existingParentid,
        [Bind("Parentid,FullName")] Parent parent, bool existingparent)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (existingparent)
            {
                children.Parentid = existingParentid;
                _context.Add(children);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return View(children);
            }else
            _context.Add(children);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            _context.Add(parent);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(children);
    }
```

Here is the controller method for the modal partial view

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ModalAction()
    {
        var MyDbContext = _context.Children.Include(C => C.Parent);
        return PartialView(await MyDbContext.ToListAsync());
    }
```

And here is the view for the Create method

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form asp-action="Create">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Select Existing Parent", "ModalAction", "Children", null, new { @class = "btn btn-flat margin",
        data_target = "#searchparent", data_toggle = "modal" })
            <input asp-for="Parentid" type="hidden" value=" " />   
        <div class="modal fade" id="searchparent">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Parent.FullName" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Parent.FullName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Parent.FullName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is the modal partial view

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
     <h4 class="modal-title">Search for Parent data table </h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>  
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
                </th>  
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" name="bparentid" id="bparentid" value="@item.ChildID" class="btn btn-block btn-success btn-xs"
                                onclick="alert(@item.ChildID)">
                            Select
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**The Question:**

How can I pass the `@item.ChildID` value from the partial view to the Create view which will then pass it as hidden value to the create controller

Comment: We need more information. Please provide [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity I was trying to provide concerning the problem domain as minimum as possible. – I will edit the question with more code… and it would be good if u suggest what I should include

Comment: @Win hope now the information is sufficient enough to look into the problem

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to change the value of the input field after the page has loaded, this needs to happen inside the user's browser, so Razor which runs server-side can't help. But you can accomplish what you want using javascript:

```
//First add an ID to your hidden input 
<input id="my-input" ... />

//Second add the following onclick to your button:
<button onclick="document.getElementById('my-input').value = this.value" ...></button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that is what i did, the problem is not accessing the item id in the partial view, as you said, i can get the item id by assigning the item id as button value like this `value="@item.Itemid". but then i want to pass the button value to the parent window (view) then post it to the controller as a hidden field

Comment: Ah I think I understand now - thanks, I've updated my answer.

Comment: I added more detail to the question